# Net Scaler cookie Insert usage

Tags: asp.net, cookies, load-balancing, httpcookie, netscaler

In our load balanced Asp.net web application, Persistent NSC (Net Scaler) cookie is created and we were asked to remove it.
Before removing we want to know 
What is NSC cookie?
What is the use of NSC cookie in load balanced web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Persistence stored there

NetScaler has [several methods to store persistence](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/11/getting-started-with-netscaler/load-balancing/configure-persistence-settings.html). In other words: how to remember where NS directed a client.

In this case the `CookieInsert` seems to have been selected. Breakdown on details here:

- [CTX124630: Best Practices and Configuration of COOKIEINSERT Persistence on NetScaler](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX124630) (Archived [here](https://archive.fo/CmlZN).)

If you don't need cookies, you can select another persistence method. Pick one from here:

- Citrix Blogs, Perumal Kalathi, 2010-06-01, [Configuring, Verifying and Monitoring Persistence on NetScaler](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2010/06/01/configuring-verifying-and-monitoring-persistence-on-netscaler/) (Archived [here](https://archive.fo/mIqPo).)

Comment: I believe cookieInsert concept is same as Persistence with Http Cookie in https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/11/traffic-management/load-balancing/load-balancing-persistence/http-cookie-persistence.html